# Sending a value through AJAX that has already been updated by AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a form that takes a number of values from a user, performs a calculation on them and outputs the result.  There is an onchange on each user edited field that fires a function that calls via AJAX the script that performs the calculation.  All good so far, this works as expected.

However, there is a modifier in a hidden field that gets updated, also by AJAX, depending on the user input of one of the fields.  I can see that this is also working and that the value is being updated.

My problem is that after this hidden field has been updated the new value in it is not sent to the script that performs the calculation.  I presume that this is because the DOM has been changed via javascript and needs refreshing but I can't work out how to do this.

This function calls the script that performs the calculation which returns an array.

```
function calcPremium()
{
    var offer = 0;
    var override = 0;

    var pio = $('#policyIntroductoryOffer').prop('checked');
    var po = $('#policyOverride').prop('checked');
    if(pio)
        {
            alert('Offer checked');
            offer = 1;
        }
    if(po)
        {
            alert('Override checked');
            override = 1;
        }

    $.ajax({
        url: "calcPremium.php",
        method: "get",
        cache: false,
        data: {
                startDate : $('#policyStartDate').val(), 
                endDate : $('#policyEndDate').val(), 
                premium : $('#policyPremium').val(), 
                premium12 : $('#policy12m').val(), 
                buildingSum : $('#policyBuildingSum').val(), 
                rentSum : $('#policyRentSum').val(), 
                <?php if((isset($_GET['cat']) and $_GET['cat'] == 2) or $propertyCat == 2)
                    { ?>
                        typeRate : 100, 
                        typeRentRate : 0, 
                        typePOLRate : 0, 
                    <?php }
                else
                    { ?>
                        typeRate : $('#typeRate').val(), 
                        typeRentRate : $('#typeRentRate').val(), 
                        typePOLRate : $('#typePOLRate').val(), 
                    <?php } ?>
                rentSum1Yr : $('#policyRentSum1Yr').val(), 
                terrorZoneRate : $('#terrorRate').val(), 
                terrorZoneRentRate : $('#terrorRentRate').val(), 
                introductoryOffer : offer, 
                policyOverride : override, 
                policyIPTRate : <?php echo $iptRates['rateRate']; ?>
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(policyDetails){
            console.info(policyDetails);

            $('#policyPremium').val(policyDetails[0]);
            $('#policy12m').val(policyDetails[1]);
            $('#policyDays').val(policyDetails[4]);
        },
        error: function(exception){
            alert('Exeption:'+exception);
        }
    })
}
```

These functions update the hidden field based on user input

```
function calcRent() {
    var r1 = document.getElementById('policyRentSum1Yr').value;
    var r3 = r1 * 3;
    <?php if((isset($_GET['cat']) and $_GET['cat'] == 2) or $propertyCat == 2)
        { ?>
            rentVal = document.getElementById('policyRentSum1Yr').value;
            if(rentVal > 0)
                {
                    setZoneRate(4);
                }
            else
                {
                    setZoneRate(5);
                }
            checkDays(document.getElementById('policyStartDate').value, document.getElementById('policyEndDate').value);
            document.getElementById('terrorRate').onshow;
            document.getElementById('policyDetails').onshow;
        <?php } ?>
    document.getElementById('policyRentSum1Yr').value = r1;
    document.getElementById('policyRentSum').value = r3;
    calcPremium();
}

function setZoneRate(z) {
    if (z == "") {
        document.getElementById('terrorRate').value = "";
        document.getElementById('terrorRentRate').value = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('terrorRates').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById('terrorRates').onshow;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","setTerrorRates.php?q="+z,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Here is a cut-down version of the form

```
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="policyAddForm" id="policyAddForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
    <h4 class="small-title">Member Details</h4>
    <input type="hidden" name="policyClient" value="<?php echo $_GET['mid']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="memberProperty" value="<?php echo $clientPropertyID; ?>" />
    <input name="clientName" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $clientName; ?>" readonly>
    <select name="clientProperty" id="clientProperty" size="1" class="form-control selectpicker" onChange="chooseProperty(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="">Select&hellip;</option>
        <option value="0">New property</option>
        <?php while($clientProps = $clientProps_stmt->fetch())
            {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $propertyID; ?>" <?php if($propertyType == NULL or $propertyTerrorismZone == NULL){?>data-content='<span class="text-danger" title="Incomplete property details, please edit"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span> <?php echo $propertyAddress1.', '.$propertyPostcode; if($propertyID == $clientPropertyID){ echo " [Contact address]"; }  if($propertyCat == 2){ echo " [Land]"; }?>'<?php } ?>><?php echo $propertyAddress1.', '.$propertyPostcode; if($propertyID == $clientPropertyID){ echo " [Contact address]"; }  if($propertyCat == 2){ echo " [Land]"; }?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <div id="clientPropertyTable">
        <span id="typeRates">
            <input type="hidden" name="typeRate" id="typeRate" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="typeRentRate" id="typeRentRate" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="typePOLRate" id="typePOLRate" value="" />
        </span>
        <span id="terrorRates">
            <input type="hidden" name="terrorRate" id="terrorRate" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="terrorRentRate" id="terrorRentRate" value="" />
        </span>
        <input name="propertyAddress1" id="propertyAddress1" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyID" id="propertyID" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyCat" id="propertyCat" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['cat']) and $_GET['cat'] == 2) {echo "2"; } else { echo "1";} ?>" />
        <input name="propertyAddress2" id="propertyAddress2" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input name="propertyTown" id="propertyTown" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input name="propertyCounty" id="propertyCounty" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input name="propertyPostcode" id="propertyPostcode" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input name="propertySqFt" id="propertySqFt" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="constructionType" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyType" value="8" />
        <input type="hidden" name="terrorZone" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyYear" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="propertyStoreys" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="the-box" id="policyDetails">
    <h4 class="small-title">Policy Details</h4>
    <input name="policyReference" type="text" class="form-control" value="" required>
    <input id="policyStartDate" name="policyStartDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="" onChange="calcPremium()" required>
    <?php $yr=date('Y');
    $dn = sanitiseDate(date('d/m/Y')); // Date now
    $rd = sanitiseDate(RENEW_DATE.$yr);  // Renewal date
    if( $dn[1]  <= $rd[1])
        {
            $theDate = RENEW_DATE.$yr;
        }
    else
        {
            $yr++;
            $theDate = RENEW_DATE.$yr;
        } ?>
    <input id="policyEndDate" name="policyEndDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $theDate; ?>" onChange="checkDays(this.value, document.getElementById('policyStartDate').value)">
    <input id="policyDays" name="policyDays" type="text" class="form-control" value="" onChange="checkDays(document.getElementById('policyStartDate').value, document.getElementById('policyEndDate').value)">
    <input name="policyIntroductoryOffer" id="policyIntroductoryOffer" type="checkbox" value="1" onChange="calcPremium();"> Introductory Offer
    <input name="policyBuildingSum" id="policyBuildingSum" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php if((isset($_GET['cat']) and $_GET['cat'] == 2) or $propertyCat == 2) {echo "250";} ?>" onChange="calcPremium();">
    <input name="policyRentSum1Yr" id="policyRentSum1Yr" type="text" class="form-control" value="" onChange="calcRent();">
    <input name="policyRentSum" id="policyRentSum" type="text" class="form-control" value="" onChange="calcPremium();" readonly>
    <input name="policyOverride" id="policyOverride" type="checkbox" value="1" onChange="calcPremium();"> QBE Override
    <input name="policyPremium" id="policyPremium" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    <input name="policy12m" id="policy12m" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
    <select name="policyStatus" class="form-control" size="1">
        <?php while($theStatus = $statusResult->fetch_assoc())
            {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $theStatus['policyStatusID']; ?>"><?php echo $theStatus['policyStatusName']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ha">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save changes
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: consider posting your code.

Comment: Thanks for that code, but you still haven't provided the most relevant part, where you bind those functions to the "input changed" events.

Comment: Isn't the call to calcPremium() in calcRent() working either?

Comment: It fires but it doesn't pick up the values that have been written to the hidden fields in the terrorRates span by the setZoneRate() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that your call to `setTerrorRates.php` is asynchronous, so it returns as soon as it's performed. This way the execution probably goes ahead with the following instructions in `calcRent()`, meaning it calls `calcPremium()` before the other call has finished its job.

The easiest way you can solve this in by declaring the call to setTerrorRates as synchronous

`xmlhttp.open("GET", "setTerrorRates.php?q=" + z, false);`

Finally, since you are using jQuery, consider taking advantage of its capabilities also in `calcRent()` and `setZoneRate()` functions.

**Edit**

You can also get rid of the `onChange` attribute of the forms that are changed programmatically. That event is triggered when the input loses focus, not when the change of its value is made via code.

I would also suggest to move all the other `onChange` values from the html code to a script. While not mandatory, it's usually a good practice to separate the presentation and the functionalities.